# Questions about array

Tags: java

Here is my code and it works perfectly fine.

```
import java.util.Random;
class apples
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Random rand = new Random();
         int frequency[] = new int[7];

         for(int roll = 1;roll < 1000;roll++){
             ++frequency[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
         }

         System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");

         for(int face = 1;face < frequency.length;face++){
             System.out.println(face + "\t" + frequency[face]);
         }
    }
}
```

I do not understand this line of code

```
++frequency[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
```

When I removed the "++" operator, it couldn't be compiled. I know that it will add 1 to the randon numbers generated from 0 to 5 but why there is a "++" in front of frequency ? Why is it neccessary to put the "++" operator there ?

Comment: Likely it was just a warning that the statement does nothing; not a compiler error. If you're able to run the program, then it was not an error, but a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `++` operator is incrementing the frequency at the specified index.  In this case, it's the same as saying:

```
for(int roll = 1;roll < 1000;roll++){
  int index = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
  frequency[index] = frequency[index] + 1;
}
```

Removing the `++` operator, you're left with:

```
for(int roll = 1;roll < 1000;roll++){
  frequency[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
}
```

The line `frequency[1+rand.nextInt(6)]` makes no sense; it is not an operation, it does not do anything.

---

**EDIT:**

Perhaps a better illustration: let `x` be the value looked up in the `frequency` array.  Then the original is equivalent to:

```
for(int roll = 1;roll < 1000;roll++){
  int x = frequency[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
  ++x; // Equivalent to "x = x + 1"
}
```

Whereas if you remove the increment operator, your resulting loop would be:

```
for(int roll = 1;roll < 1000;roll++){
  int x = frequency[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
  x; // ...what?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement without the ++ looks at the contents of the array, but does not do anything with the value. Adding the ++ operator tells it to increment the value found there.

You probably are thinking that `frequency[1+rand.nextInt(6)]` is adding a value to the array. It is not. It is looking up a location in memory from a random location.

Answer (score 0):

++ is a shorthand for

```
int i = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
frequency[i] = frequency[i] + 1;
```

Removing it causes no increment expression is executed.

Answer (score 0):

that line is equivalent to this line of code

```
int index = 1+rand.nextInt(6);
frequency[index] = frequency[index]+1 ;
```

so if you removed '++' you make the statement  incomplete like the following:

```
 int x= 5;
 x;
```

so it gives you error